# Properties file - Remote x Local

Tags: java, git, maven, heroku, wildfly-swarm

I have a properties file to handle my datasource. This file is loaded by properties maven plugin. When loaded I use on wildfly Swarm plugin.

database.properties:

```
database.server=localhost
database.server.port=3306
database.name=XXXXXXX
database.options=
database.user=XXXXXXX
database.password=XXXXXXXX
database.pool.min=1
database.pool.max=10
database.pool.preFill=true
```

Properties maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${properties-maven.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <files>
                <file>src/main/resources/database.properties</file>
            </files>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Wildfly Swarm plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>
        <configuration>
            <properties>
                <swarm.datasources.data-sources.CondominioDs.driver-name>mysql</swarm.datasources.data-sources.CondominioDs.driver-name>
                <swarm.datasources.data-sources.CondominioDs.connection-url>jdbc:mysql://${database.server}:${database.server.port}/${database.name}${database.options}</swarm.datasources.data-sources.CondominioDs.connection-url>
                <swarm.datasources.data-sources.CondominioDs.initial-pool-size>${database.pool.min}</swarm.datasources.data-sources.CondominioDs.initial-pool-size>
                <swarm.datasources.data-sources.CondominioDs.max-pool-size>${database.pool.max}</swarm.datasources.data-sources.CondominioDs.max-pool-size>
                <swarm.datasources.data-sources.CondominioDs.pool-prefill>${database.pool.preFill}</swarm.datasources.data-sources.CondominioDs.pool-prefill>
                <swarm.datasources.data-sources.CondominioDs.user-name>${database.user}</swarm.datasources.data-sources.CondominioDs.user-name>
                <swarm.datasources.data-sources.CondominioDs.password>${database.password}</swarm.datasources.data-sources.CondominioDs.password>
                <swarm.datasources.data-sources.CondominioDs.check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</swarm.datasources.data-sources.CondominioDs.check-valid-connection-sql>
            </properties>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>package</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Everything works well. Both remotely and locally.

I use Git too and I have two branchs. One (master) to update my remote repository and other (development) to code and tests.

Finally, I use Heroku to deploy my application and I use maven plugin for this (not git).

My question is about the datasource properties file. I don't know how to have two versions of file. One to use when I'm coding (locally) and other to use when I needs deploy the application on Heroku.

Of course, the address, the user and the password of locally database is different the remotely database.

This moment, I put remotely information in the properties file and deploy on Heroku. Then I came back with the local information to continue coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're using the properties format for configuration; I'd suggest moving to the YAML format. Using that, WildFly Swarm supports configuration profiles.

In your case, which is probably fairly typical, I'd put common configuration into `project-defaults.yml`, your local configuration into `project-local.yml` and your Heroku/production configuration into `project-prod.yml` (or `project-heroku.yml`, your choice). Then, you pick the correct configuration when running the app: `java -jar myapp-swarm.jar -Slocal` (or `-Sprod`).

For more info, see http://docs.wildfly-swarm.io/2017.11.0/#_configuration_of_a_wildfly_swarm_application

Comment: additionally, you'll want to pick up the DB connection params from env vars instead of hard-coding them in the file. This will ensure that your app can connect to the DB addon even if it's URL changes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using Maven, why not use its "filtering" capabilities to supply property values at build time?  Surely putting usernames and passwords in the source control repo isn't a good idea anyway.

In any case, while you *could* try some sort of branch-based hack to keep a local and remote version of the same file, there's not really a good way to ensure they "stay separate" during necessary merges to carry other changes across the branches.

So if you insist on using git as the storage place for environment-specific property values, about the best you can do is store each environment's version with a different filename, and make up the difference in the build process.  (Again the easiest way I can think to do that with Maven is filtering, so you'd still be doing almost all of the same work as you would to fully remove the values from source control...)

Comment: I can use Maven resource filtering (and profile too)..... but..... my password continue in the Pom.xml and I can't send it to my remote repository, right?  I looked at the following sites: http://roufid.com/filter-and-rename-resources-with-maven/  and https://portofino.manydesigns.com/en/docs/portofino3/tutorials/using-maven-profiles-and-resource-filtering